# Why can't I make this image a link using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following in my Angular view:

```
    <a ui-sref="mystate({'stateParam1': 99, 'stateParam1': 98})" ng-bind="myCtrl.something.something.username">
    </a>

    <img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{myCtrl.something.something.md5Email}}"/>
```

It works perfectly. I see a link (for my username), followed by a nice Gravatar image of myself.

But I actually want my image and my username to both be in the body of the link. How can I do that? I tried the following but it only showed my username, not the image:

```
    <a ui-sref="mystate({'stateParam1': 99, 'stateParam1': 98})" ng-bind="myCtrl.something.something.username"> 
      <img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{myCtrl.something.something.md5Email}}"/>
    </a>
```

Comment: It should work, can you set up a fiddle with that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ng-bing changes entire text in a tag. So what is contained in enclosing a tag, that is changing with model from ng-bind which is changed to text. 
I think that Angular takes `<a>xx</a>`  and sets it to variable.

```
var c = xx;
c = ng-bind
<a>c</a>
```

So in result we have new variable with data from ng-bind.

Could You use you img inside ng-bind?